# laravel featch data from database in chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, charts

I hava table product

- id
- name

I would like to fetch data from database in a chart.
And of course this breaks the chart and it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$products= Product::all();
return view('/')->with('products',$products) ;
```

**Javascript :**

```
function drawStacked() {

       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        @foreach($products as $product)],

          [ '{{$product->name}}',  '', '#000', {{$product->name}} ],

         @endforeach  

      ]);

      var options = {
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'All Product',
          minValue: 0,
        }
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```